# Правильная постановка тире

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли я поставила тире в этих предложениях? И нужны ли еще запятые?

Ромуальд <...> с головой ушел в работу – это стало для него самым лучшим лекарством. И так чрезвычайно работоспособный, целеустремленный, энергичный – он ставил перед собой все новые и новые задачи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё правильно: "Ромуальд <...> с головой ушел в работу – это стало для него самым лучшим лекарством. И так чрезвычайно работоспособный, целеустремленный, энергичный – он ставил перед собой все новые и новые задачи".

Пояснение

Обособление однородного ряда определений связано с его актуализацией в связи дополнительным обстоятельственным значением сопоставления и уступки, которое задает сочетание "и так".

Если поставить запятую, то это будет обычное обособление ряда, отнесенного к личному местоимению (только определительное значение), например: Чрезвычайно работоспособный, целеустремленный, энергичный, он ставил перед собой все новые и новые задачи.

Answer (score 1):

Первое тире объяснимо и понятно. А вот второе я не поставил бы, а вместо него написал бы запятую, ведь слова "И так чрезвычайно работоспособный, целеустремленный, энергичный" - это определение, стоящее перед определяемым словом, но определяемое слово выражено личным местоимением, поэтому перед "он" ставится запятая.

Comment: Виктор, но по правилам, если обобщающее слово следует за однородными членами, то перед ним ставится тире.Ср.напр.похожий пример:Ни ты, ни она  -  вы не забудете того, что случилось (Пушкин). Здесь тире тоже стоит перед личным местоимением.

Comment: Уважаемый Серж! Слова "чрезвычайно работоспособный, целеустремленный, энергичный" - это ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЯ,а слово "он" является определяемым словом, а не обобщающим словом. У Розенталя правило звучит так (цитирую): "Обособляется определение, относящееся к личному местоимению, независимо от степени распространенности и местоположения определения.

Comment: Виктор, а как Вы объясните тире в этом предложении " Ни ты, ни она - вы не забудете того, что случилось (Пушкин).?

Comment: Вы - это обобщающее слово для местоимений "Ты, она", поэтому тире верно стоит.

Answer (score 1):

В соответствии с правилами пунктуации, обособляется определение, относящееся к личному местоимению, независимо от степени распространенности и местоположения определения.
В данном случае плюс ко всему оборот имеет добавочное обстоятельственное значение (будучи).

И так чрезвычайно работоспособный, целеустремленный, энергичный, он ставил перед собой все новые и новые задачи.

Comment: Верно, Татьяна, я вчера именно так, слово в слово, отвечал на этот вопрос в комментарии

Answer (score 0):

Да, тире расставлены верно. Согласно правилам, если вторая часть сложного предложения представляет собой присоединительное предложение (перед ним можно вставить слово *это*, которое иногда имеется в самом предложении), тире ставится. Например: На стене ни одного образа  -  дурной знак (Лермонтов); Инга была возбуждена, Левшин наблюдал за ней слишком пристально  -  ***это бросилось Клебе в глаза (Федин).***
Во втором случае тире обосновано однородными членами.